# how to store input box number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine how a normal calculator do. Use click button to input the data in a display box. Now i want to click a button to show "+" and also remove all the number in display but store it. So I can click to show the new number. After that, store those data include number1, "+" and number 2. For example: ("1","+" "2"). The reason of doing that but not using javascript for normal calculating is because I want to use Ajax to send to php and use php to execute the maths.However, I get stuck in this part.

```
var memory = "";
$("#add").click(function() {
  memory += $show.val() + "+";
  if($show.val().length >= 1){
    $show.val("+");
  } else {
    $show.val("");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Obligatory warning against evaluated code from a string on a server]

I would recommend trying to get a working version of your project using only javascript before trying more advanced concepts.

```
var memory = [];

$("#add").click(function() {
    var val = $show.val();
    if (val)
        memory.push(val);
    $show.val('+');
});

$('#submit').click(function () {
    var s = memory.join('+');
    memory = [];
    $.get(...
});
```

Comment: thank you for answering. In this case is that mean var val store the first number and the var s store the second number with adding a + on it?

Comment: `val` stores the most recently entered character (assumed to be a number).  `memory` is an array that holds all the `val`s in order.  `s` holds the `val`s with '+' interspersed.

Comment: what if i want to create more button such as multiply and divide. So var s = memory.join('+'); that "+" is just a string right? Can i do it like var s = memory.join('.operator');  ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2zwwu7vk/)

```js
var one = $("#one");
var two = $("#two");
var add = $("#add");
var show = $("#show");
var equal = $("#equal");
var memory = "";

one.click(function(){
  memory += "1";    
  show.val("1");
});

two.click(function(){
  memory +=  "2"; 
  show.val("2");
});

add.click(function(){
  memory +=  "+";
  if(show.val().length >= 1)
    show.val("+");
  else
    show.val("");      
});

equal.click(function(){
  show.val(memory)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="show" type="text"/>
<input id="one" type="button" value="1"/>
<input id="two" type="button" value="2"/>
<input id="add" type="button" value="+"/>
<input id="equal" type="button" value="="/>
```

Comment: Have same concern on processing such calculation on the server as per @twinlakes answer